# How to restore Alt-Middle mouse to view snap mode?

Tags: 3d-view

In the new Blender versions Alt + Middle mouse now changes frames in the timeline. I'm used to using it in the previous default where I could drag between different view positions with Alt + Middle Mouse. What settings in keymap do I need to change to go back?

I've been looking but it's not obvious!

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that I had enabled the "Grease Pencil Tools" addon, which uses this hotkey for scrubbing the timeline.

If you still want this addon enabled, you can rebind that action by going to Preferences -> Addons -> Grease Pencil Tools -> Timeline Scrub and choosing a different hotkey. Alt + Middle click should now zoom the camera to the cursor, and Alt + Middle drag should snap to views again.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a little bug: the function you're looking for is called "Center view to mouse". it looks correctly setted, but it doesn't work: looks like it works as if the dopesheet window was the active one.

I could restore it adding the shift modifier (Alt Shift MMB).

[image]

Comment: Still seems to be ignoring the input for me. Even if I use shift modifier and disable change frame in the dopesheet keymap. Could be a bug like you say. The Blender 3.0 alpha also did this.

Comment: Did you add the shift key in the preferences Keymap panel? Tested in 2.93.